# Can I say "people that I'm not familiar with" ?

Tags: grammar

Hello everyone I would like to know if my sentence is or is not correct.

"I don't share my hobbies when I speak to someone is not aware of them like a relevant, a wife, and anyone that I'm not familiar with."

Comment: "People that" or "anyone that" is fine, but the rest just makes no sense. You seem to be missing some words. The sentence does not parse. And who is "a relevant"? Do you mean "a relative"?

Comment: I'd say "anyone that I'm unfamiliar with".

Comment: sorry I meant "someone ((that)) is not aware of them. "  and yea, I mean relative...